# Windows 8 Desktop program uninstallation

Tags: windows-8

How can i uninstall a program in Windows 8 in desktop without going to the start screen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Open the **Computer** in **File Explorer**.
2. Click **Computer** on the **Ribbon** and select **Uninstall or change a program**
   [image]

Comment: What about just clicking "Uninstall or change a program" instead of "Open Control Panel"? :D

Comment: @SeToY apparently that is a quicker way. Thanks. Edited

Answer (score 5):

There are three ways to do this:

- Go to `Control Center`>`More Settings`>`Programs and features` and there you may uninstall programs.
- Go to the installation directory of the program and run the uninstaller directly.
- Use a third-party tool such as [CCleaner](http://piriform.com/ccleaner/)

**Hint:** You can open the control center via `Win`+`R`>`control>`>`{Enter}`

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1**

1. Key in <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
2. Click on Computer at Upper Ribbon
3. Click on **Add or Remove Program** next to the icon for the Control Panel
4. Uninstall it.

**Method 2**

1. Key in <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then key in <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Method 3**

1. Control Center → More Settings → Programs and Features
2. Then uninstall it.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are not wanting to know how to uninstall using the Start Menu.

**Using the Start Menu**

Right Click on the program you want to uninstall and click on uninstall program

**Using the control Panel**

1. Press Windows Key + E
2. Click on Computer in the upper toolbar
3. Click on Add or Remove Program next to the icon for the Control Panel
4. Uninstall your program

Answer (score 3):

I usually follow this steps:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>:

   [image]
2. On "System" properties, top left side of the screen there is a shortcut to "Control Panel Home". Click on it.
3. Click on "Uninstall a Program" from control panel and you will be able to uninstall whatever you may want:

[image]

Comment: Where is the 'break' key?

Comment: @GabrielFair: It also goes by the name Pause. :) (On certain keyboards, especially on laptops, an additional Fn key press might be required which makes the whole thing very unwieldy.)

Answer (score 1):

You can access the control panel from the File Explorer browsing your Computer, then **Uninstall a program**.

Uninstalling a program is quite similar to in Windows 7. From the start screen, just go to **Control Panel > More settings > Programs and Features**, and select the program to Uninstall.

If you know where the uninstaller for a program is, you can also find it directly using the File Explorer.

To uninstall a Metro/Modern UI application, right-click the application, and click Uninstall from the menu that pops up.

Answer (score 0):

### WinX Menu

1. Move your mouse pointer to the bottom left corner, and right-click the Start button when it appears.
   Alternatively press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.
2. Click **Programs and Features**.

WinX menu also has **Control Panel** item.

### Charms Bar

1. Move your mouse pointer to upper or bottom right corner of the screen, Charms Bar will appear.
   Alternatively, press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.
2. Click **Settings**.
3. Click **Control Panel**.
4. Click **Uninstall a program**.